# Bootstrap - Auto expanding container, row & row columns' width with content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have following html:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul>
            <li>Long Content 1<li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul>
            <li>Long Content 2<li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I will be adding dynamic content into each **ul** element. I want **col-md-*** elements and their parents to expand  themselves horizontally with the content, even if they horizontally overflow the screen window. I don't mind horizontal scrolling on the screen. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I assume you are using Bootstrap for the rest of the project?

Comment: yes i am using Bootstrap

Comment: Bootstrap version 3?

Comment: yes Bootstrap v3

Answer (score 1):

Replace `container`to `container-fluid`

Comment: I don't think that will be of help since container-fluid will just expand the container till screen-width. My content is longer and will expand beyond screen-width.

Comment: use `overflow-x:scroll` or `overflow-x:auto` property in `container`

Comment: These overflow properties will help only when content goes beyond container's width ... which container is not allowing in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `display:inline-block` property of css for the li. Please see the example below:

```css
ul li{
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul>
            <li>Long Content 1<li>
            <li>Long Content 1<li>
            <li>Long Content 1<li>
            <li>Long Content 1<li>
            <li>Long Content 1<li>
            <li>Long Content 1<li>
            <li>Long Content 1<li>
            <li>Long Content 1<li>
            <li>Long Content 1<li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul>
            <li>Long Content 2<li>
            <li>Long Content 2<li>
            <li>Long Content 2<li>
            <li>Long Content 2<li>
            <li>Long Content 2<li>
            <li>Long Content 2<li>
            <li>Long Content 2<li>
            <li>Long Content 2<li>
            <li>Long Content 2<li>
            <li>Long Content 2<li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of multiple li, there will be one li element, but it will have a long content. I want that content to be expandable such that if it overflow .container element, the .container element adjust its width with it.

Answer (score 0):

This will force the element to NEVER wrap text and should help with what you're looking for.

```
li{white-space:nowrap}
```

You may need to change the li element to display:block as well

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing around with this a bit. I ended up with this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/05y3mra5/1/). I didn t manage to get bootstrap loaded properly so I added in some css to replicate the bootstrap .col-md-6 behavior. I basically added white-space: nowrap to the li-items. And also enabled vertical scrolling on the divs. I figured that would be about what you wanted to do.

**html**

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 scrollbox">
        <ul>
            <li>Long Content 1 nkjdfhkjfh dskjfhdkjs hkjdsh fkjdshkjf hdkjshf kjh fkdsk fjhkj dhfkjshfkj das fdkjsfkjdsfkj hks fkadsj f last word<li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 scrollbox">
        <ul> 
            <li>Long Content 2<li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
li{
 white-space: nowrap;
}
/*col-md-6 code is to simulate bootstrap*/
.col-md-6{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.scrollbox{
  background-color: rgb(200,200,220);
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```